# Screen is dim but goes back on when I tap on the back bottom of the display

Tags: windows-8, display, lenovo-laptop

I have no idea what happened to my Window 8 Lenovo Laptop p500 touch . I'm assuming the inverter is loose or something? every time I shut my laptop, or i bump into it, it goes dim.

I can still see it, but I need light to do so. the only way I can fix it is when I tap the back of the Display where the blacklight/inverter is.

Could anyone tell what's happening to my laptop, and how much it would be to fix it.

Edit* I found something new, when I carefully move the display, making sure it doesn't go dim again. sometimes, the display has like a green, red, Pixels.

I look up a diagnostic where if you slightly flex the side of the display to see if anything happens. When I did this, the some part of the screen goes green, red, then goes completely white.

After I let the side of the display go, it goes back to being dim where, Again, I can tap the the display where the inverter is to fix it.

Does that mean anything?

Comment: It sounds like a loose connection between the backlight and inverter, an easy fix if you know what you are doing. As to how much it would cost depends on who you take it too for repair, typically around 40/50 bucks I would think, as long as there is nothing else wrong like a faulty inverter or backlight then it would cost more.

Comment: thank you. I'll go have it repaired. if i could find the accept button, I would accept your answer.